# Making a mess of read and write

Tags: java, swing

Ok what I am trying to do is read from one .text file to another text file using a button.  So it's event driven but i have to reverse the output.

I am coding in netbeans because I am a newb and it is helpfull.

I have been working on this for a couple of days trying to find clear info on the web but I am having a hard time and now my code I think looks worse than when I started so please point out why what I am doing is wrong.

Thank you so much in advance for any advice that you can give.

Here is my button.

```
        private void ReadButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int x ;
        Vector<String> readOrder = new Vector<String>();
        try {
        Scanner i = new Scanner(new FileReader("Out.txt"));
        while( i.hasNextInt()){
        x = i.nextInt();
        readOrder.add(new Integer(x));
        }
        try {
        try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Outfile.txt")));
        out.append(" " + x);
        out.close();
        }
        i.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e ){}
        for(int i = readOrder.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
        System.out.println( readOrder.elementAt( i ).intValue() );
        }
```

Comment: There isn't really a question here.  What specifically is the problem that you're seeing with your code?

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you are looking for a review

Comment: If it's advice you're looking for, maybe you could indent your code?

Comment: I am guess you want readOrder.add(0, new Integer(x)); instead, if you are trying to reverse the input. (Note the first 0 argument).

Comment: Don't use a scanner to read in the file, use BufferedReader, also do have to reverse just the word order or the whole character order? Using a stringbuilder you can reverse the text order

Comment: Gobernador you are right about the way the code looks.  I need to clean that up.

Comment: Sam Palmer.  Thank you for the idea of the Buffered Reader I will research that some more and try and work with it.

  I will also look at the string builder.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @Brian: You didn't really say what the problem was here?

Answer (score 1):

To improve your code,

1. Remove the nested try catch, into two separate try-catch block one for input and one for output.
2. Remove the `try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Outfile.txt")))` One outer block will be adequate.
3. Separate the IO, business & file logic by putting them in different class and IF NEEDED (only) behind interfaces.
4. I don't know if you have a specific reason for using vector (It has advantages like contiguously stored in memory etc) but a ArrayList should be sufficient of reading a list of ints.
5. `Collections.reverse(arrayList);` java.util.Collections is a useful method for your reversal logic, if its an assignment/exercise then your teacher won't appreciate using lib methods :)

Comment: Zasz thank you so much for walking me through my mistakes.  You have no idea how valuable your input was for me.  Thank you so much for taking time out of your day to teach me more about what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Filein.txt"));
StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
while(br.ready()){
build.append(br.readline());
}
build.reverse(); //Reverses the order of all the characters in the builder

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Fileout.txt"));

try{
bw.write(build.toString());
bw.flush();
bw.close();

}catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: Also looking at your code, it is best to modularise it into separate methods, this will make it easier to read and debug

Comment: I see what you are saying about the BufferedReader.  It cuts the ammount of code you need way down and I was already trying to use the BufferedWriter.  In the build.append(br.readline()); though should that be surrounded with a do { though?

Comment: No as it is in the while loop br.ready already. So if the buffer is empty it will break the loop

Comment: With some very modest changes that worked out very well.  You were correct and I was way out there with my first set of code.  I also found that you can reverse just the words in the string and not the entire string in one shot and that is cool.  I can't wait to work on something else.  I have so much to learn.

Comment: Good luck, and out of interest how did you reverse the words?